# R Nesting Formulas

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the syntax of R and having difficulty when we nest formulas.

In this case, I am trying to:

1. select everything in column "Y" that is equal to one
2. then give me unique values in column "X" when #1 is true.

I know how to do this in two steps but not in a nested format.

Thank you

> subset(data, Y == "1") %>%
> unique("X")

Comment: `unique(subset(mtcars, carb == 1)$gear)` is an example using the built-in `mtcars` dataset. The `subset` part outputs a smaller data frame, and we can extract the `gear` column from it using `$gear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `magrittr` pipes using

```
subset(mtcars, carb == 1) %$% gear %>% unique()
```

and with base pipes or `magrittr` pipes using

```
subset(mtcars, carb == 1)$gear |> unique()
```

or

```
subset(mtcars, carb == 1)$gear %>% unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using `data.table` library, it is not necessary to nest. For example, using the `mtcars` dataset, returning the unique value of column `cyl` when column `carb` equals 1 is as follows:

```
library(data.table)

mtcars

data.table(mtcars)[carb == 1, unique(cyl)]
```